# FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images

Tags: python, opencv

i hava problem in fire detection 
my code is :

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
L , a , b = cv2.split(lab_image)
ret,thresh_L = cv2.threshold(L,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ret,thresh_a = cv2.threshold(a,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ret,thresh_b = cv2.threshold(b,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
thresh_image = cv2.merge((thresh_L, thresh_a, thresh_b))
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh_image, None, iterations=2)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(thresh_image,cv2.COLOR_
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < args["min_area"]:
        continue
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRecy(c)
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imshow('frame1',frame)
```

and when i run this program , see this error

```
FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images in function cvStartFindContours
```

please help me . 
tnx

Answer (score 57):

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Use this line on your image to convert it from BGR to grayscale (8UC1) format before finding contours. FindContours function only supports a grayscale image format.

Answer (score 28):

In my **solution** I had to **convert** the `dtype` into `uint8`.

Yes, my image was binary image(single channel), however in my code somehow the  `thresh_image` was changed into `float32` data type. But `cv2.findContours()`  cannot handle `float32`.

So I had to **explicitly convert** `float32` **-->** `uint8`.

```py
thresh_image = thresh_image.astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 3):

For completion, the `8UC1` format is 8 byte, unsigned, single channel.
In addition to cv2 grayscale, single-channel `uint8` format will also be valid, in case anyone is building the image outside of cv2 functions and encounters this error.

Answer (score 1):

The documention of `findContours` is clearly saying that it can afford to take single channel images as inputs(i.e 8uc1 and 32sc1) But you are sending 3 channel image.here is the documentation of findcontours http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and found the cause:

I created:  `gray_img = np.zeros((width,height,3),np.uint8)`

In gray_img, depth = 3, it doesn't match findContours.

Then I recreated: `gray_img = np.zeros((width,height),np.uint8)`

it worked.