# Shape matching using shape contours detection

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

temp = cv2.imread('./image/star.jpg')
ret, temp_thre = cv2.threshold(temp, 100, 255,0)

cv2.imshow("store gray iamge",temp_thre)
cv2.waitKey(0)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(temp_thre, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
temp_cont = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse= True)

new_temp_cont = temp_cont[1]

tar = cv2.imread('./image/store.jpg')
tar_gray = cv2.cvtColor(tar, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
tar_thr = cv2.threshold(tar_gray, 127, 255, 0)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(tar_thr, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for c in contours:
    match = cv2.matchShapes(new_temp_cont, c, 1, 0.0)
    print(match)
    if match < 0.15:
        closest_match = c
    else:
        closest_match = []
cv2.drawContours(tar, [closest_match], -1, (0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow("output", tar)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my code but I still haven't been able to rectify it. Please help me in this regard.

---

Error arrived here is:

```
C:\python36\python.exe C:/Users/shahid/PycharmProjects/untitled/segmentation_object_detection.py
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats ([Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only) in cvStartFindContours_Impl, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 199
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shahid/PycharmProjects/untitled/segmentation_object_detection.py", line 10, in <module>
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(temp_thre, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`enter code here`
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:199: error: (-210) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function cvStartFindContours_Impl
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438646/findcontours-support-only-8uc1-and-32sc1-images)

Answer (score 0):

Your image has too many channels in it for findContours, which requires a single channel 8-bit image.  Here's how to get info on a source image:

```
temp = cv2.imread('./image/star.jpg')
print('shape={}'.format(temp.shape))
```

If there are 2 elements in the shape then image is single channel.  If 3, then the 3rd element is the number of channels.

You'll need to convert the image to single channel 8 bit image, for example:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(temp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```